# Load content from PHP file when a link is clicked using AJAX

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to learn ajax to get results from YQL.

I have "amz" division.

This is what I intend to do,

- When I click on a link in "amz" division
- I would get the artist name and send that to yahoo.php which takes $_GET["artist"] and returns output.
- This output has to be updated in division with id="yah"

I checked in Firebug to see if the GET is working, but no parameter is being sent!

The artist name alert from attribute "name" is working, so no problem there.

I am stuck! I don't know why this isn't working, any suggestions please?

P.S : This is a Facebook application. Guess it doesn't make any difference!?

```
  <div id="amz"><!-- some links here --></div>


 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#amz a').click(function(){               
            alert($(this).attr("name")); 
            var value = "artist=" + (this).attr("name");   
            var obj = $.get("yahoo.php",value,function(data){  
            $("#yah").html("data!");  
            alert('Load was performed.');
        })          
        .error(function() { alert("error"); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });        
        });
      });
```

---

Solved! The problem :Placing the script tag in "head"
Placed it just before "body" and worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#amz').click(function() {
      var artistName = 'John';
      $.ajax({
         url: 'artist.php',
         type: 'get',
         data: {
            artist: artistName
         },
         sucess: function(response) {
            $('#yah').html(response);
         }
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :( Well get or ajax shouldn't make any difference as $.get is like shortcut for $.ajax .Thanks for the reply.

Comment: What happens if you open the artist.php file in your browser? Also, is the artist.php file in the same directory as the file where you include your javascript?

Comment: yahoo.php has echo statements . INDEX.php is like this :
<?php include("inc/header.php"); ?> 
.....
<?php include("inc/footer.php"); ?> ; The script is in header.php and yahoo.php is in the root folder (NOT IN INC FOLDER),the same folder where index.php is..